# iAd issue in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I just finished my App with iAds, and  For removing ads I implement an In-App purchase in my application.

I want to know it is right that to remove the ads the user pays, but when the user deletes the app and reinstalls it again, iAds show again (because I am not using web services).

The alternate way is that I make two apps with same functionality, one with iAds and one without iAds. Please suggest me the right approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is the correct functionality. But, if the user wants to remove the ads again after deleting/reinstalling your application they can 're-purchase' your in-app purchase for no charge to remove the ads again.

Answer (score 0):

@M.S.B In case you are implementing in app to remove ads , it is an right approach. And in case the user deletes the app and re installs again ,tries to buy the in app the app store will show it as already purchased if the In app is an non-consumable in the app store. You can maintain BOOL value for the in app , so that you can track and hide your ads.